# Reading a file into a python dictionary with and without delimiters

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I am trying to find a quick way to parse a file into dictionary in python.  The file has a bunch of lines, some with values of interest and some without as follows:

```
Not of interest
Key1=Value1
Not of interest
Key2=Value2
Key3=Value3
```

If I edit the file and remove all of lines that I am not interested in, I can run the following command:

```
>>> dict(item.split("=") for item in open("testfile"))
{'Key3': 'Value3\n', 'Key2': 'Value2\n', 'Key1': 'Value1\n'}
```

But with the other lines in I get the following:

```
>>> dict(item.split("=") for item in open("testfile"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

I was thinking one way of achieving this would be to read the whole file into a list, creating a new list with just the interesting lines and then running the above command against that list.

I'd really appreciate it anyone could comment on the best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check to see if there is an `=` in the line using the `in` keyword.

```
dict(item.split("=") for item in open("testfile") if "=" in item)
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks nicer than my own attempt!

Answer (score 0):

So the best I have come up with is:

```
>>> import re
>>> file = open("test").readlines()
>>> dict(item.split("=") for item in [line for line in file if re.match('.*=.*', line)])
{'Key3': 'Value3\n', 'Key2': 'Value2\n', 'Key1': 'Value1\n'}
>>>>
```

I'd still welcome feedback if there is a better way, but if not hopefully it's of use to someone!

Chris